# How to retrieve/implement user/role based execution in Hyperledger v1.0?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to build an application in Hyperledger v1.0 which has the following features,

- Multi-sig contract execution
- Discoverability of contracts
- Selective
  visibility.

But I am not able to find,

- Any functions to retrieve role/user information
- Define and create users with different roles.

Any examples on how can I make my smart contract discoverable by other smart contracts will also be highly appreciated.

Comment: > Any examples on how can I make my smart contract discoverable by other smart contracts will also be highly appreciated.

can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the certificate of the creator of the proposal in the chaincode execution in the following way:

```
        creatorByte, err := stub.GetCreator()
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("Error stub.GetCreator")
    }
    bl, _ := pem.Decode(creatorByte)
    if bl == nil {
        return shim.Error("Could not decode the PEM structure")
    }
    cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(bl.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("ParseCertificate failed")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but by this I will get the identity of the user. Don't we have a user-role mapping in v1.0 as we had in v0.6? To implement a role based logic (For eg. all buyers should be able to see the price quote from a particular supplier but no supplier should be able to see the price) we will need to know the identities of all the organizations involved.

Comment: Do you mean something like: https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5346
?

Comment: Yes, role based access in chaincode. 
In v0.6 it was done as specified in Listing 11 in https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-ibm-blockchain-chaincode-development-using-golang/index.html

Only the bank home loan admin can create the home loan application and no one else. Similarly, only the buyer can see the price list of the supplier and no one else.

Comment: What´s the structure of a parsed certificate (cert variable)

Answer (score 1):

**First Question:**

> Any functions to retrieve role/user information

This is done using the [CID](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.3/core/chaincode/lib/cid/README.md) library.

> The client identity chaincode library enables you to write chaincode which makes access control decisions based on the identity of the client (i.e. the invoker of the chaincode). In particular, you may make access control decisions based on either or both of the following associated with the client:
>
> - the client identity's MSP (Membership Service Provider) ID
> - an attribute associated with the client identity.
>     Attributes are simply name and value pairs associated with an identity. For example, email=me@gmail.com indicates an identity has the email attribute with a value of me@gmail.com

For Nodejs: https://fabric-shim.github.io/master/fabric-shim.ClientIdentity.html

**Second Question:**

> Define and create users with different roles.

https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#attribute-based-access-control

```
fabric-ca-client register --id.name user1 --id.secret user1pw --id.type user --id.affiliation org1 --id.attrs 'app1Admin=true:ecert,email=user1@gmail.com'
```

or while enrolling

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://user1:user1pw@localhost:7054 --enrollment.attrs "email,phone:opt"
```

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.3/core/chaincode/lib/cid/README.md:

> the Attributes are stored inside the X509 certificate as an extension with an ASN.1 OID (Abstract Syntax Notation Object IDentifier) of 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1. The value of the extension is a JSON string of the form {"attrs":{:

see https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.3/fabric-ca/README.md for

> How to use the Hyperledger Fabric CA client and server to generate all crypto material rather than using cryptogen. The cryptogen tool is not intended for a production environment because it generates all private keys in one location which must then be copied to the appropriate host or container. This sample demonstrates how to generate crypto material for orderers, peers, administrators, and end users so that private keys never leave the host or container in which they are generated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm goingo to answer single point of your question:

> Define and create users with different roles.

When you create a user or a component, you create it via Fabric CA, i.e. when you create something, you define what it is going to be: peer, orderer, user... So, the kind of user that it is depends on its role.

I don't know if I answered any or your questions. Could you give more info about them?

Comment: Thanks. But I meant roles depending on the user and not the components, let's take an example of a market place. In that there will be x suppliers and they might have uploaded their pricing details as a smart contract. Now, only the buyer should be able to query and see the price of the smart contracts. This can be achieved if we assign different roles to suppliers and buyers and then restrict the viewing rights depending on the role of the person quering the smart contract.

Comment: Hi! First, I'm sorry if I didn't understand well your question. Second, I think that you confuse the term Smart Contract: it means to the code that it is deployed on the Blockchain. There you can write what you want. i.e. your code. For example, a solution for you could be that the suppliers would encrypt their pricing details with the public key of the buyer and then the buyer could query and see them. Also, you can write a Smart Contract to filter the functions of each user depending on its role, you can restrict the viewing rights on the Smart Contract.

Comment: I agree, that, to encrypt the content with buyer's public key is one way to do it. But I was interested in the second way that you specified, as how do I restrict the viewing rights based on role in v1.0. I was able to do that in v0.6 using the getCertAttribute Function and extracting the role and user information.

Comment: I think that @yacovm answers to it in the previos answer.